# Swift NSURLConnection returns instantly with a 1005 error

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I working on a new app written in swift, I've seen this error message spammed all over SO saying: Restart the simulator.

Too bad it seems that in my case this is not the answer, an older app written in objective-C which seems to be using exactly the same methods does work fine, but when I make NSUrlConnection calls to an Api (ours) it does not seem to work for the new app.

The response is a proper 200 with some json data, no redirects it works fine on the Android app I'm developing simultaneously.

basicly what I have:

```
func getRequest() -> NSMutableURLRequest {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: package.fullPath)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = package.apiMethod.description;
        request.HTTPBody = "hi".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        return request;
    }

    func execute() {
        conn = NSURLConnection(request: getRequest(), delegate: self);
        if let c = conn {
            Debug.log("** api-connection-start **");
        }

    }
```

relevant listeners (the class implements NSURLConnectionDataDelegate):

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
    Debug.log("** api-recieved-url-response? **")
    let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
    statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
    Debug.log("** api-recieving-data **")
    self.responseData.appendData(data)
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    Debug.log("** api-fail-with-error **")
    ErrorClass.message(error)
    if let responseListener = listener {
        responseListener.onError(package, error:error)
    }
}
```

I have breakpoints on all those helper methods, only the didFailWith error is instantly called with an error containing:

```
2015-03-31 16:58:29.853 myappname[537:4136] {
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://xxxxxxxx/valid/api/call";
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "http://xxxxxxxx/valid/api/call";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The network connection was lost.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 \"The network connection was lost.\" UserInfo=0x7fdf3bc465d0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xxxxxxxx/valid/api/call, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxxxxxx/valid/api/call, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}";
    "_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey" = "-4";
    "_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey" = 4;
}
```

Obviously I replaced the company name and exact called url since I cannot share these, I can guarantee that these are correct though.

Does anyone see a mistake causing my tissues?

Comment: 1005 is network connection lost. Are you sure you are connected to the Internet

Comment: The polder objectieve c app connects using nsurl connection just fine. Alsof using safari also works

Comment: I have the feeling that it now actually works, even though I even rebooted yesterday, I guess I should take more time looking into cleaning the project fully besides hitting clean and rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After crying lots of hours till I fell asleep and waking up and returning to work it magically works again.

Thanks Obama!
Anyway, just make sure you clear all data from xcode besides cleaning, this can sadly cause these issues too, not just restarting the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The error is "network connection lost".

That's an error that you have to expect at any time, because the user of your app can lose their network connection at any time. And it can come back at any time.

It is not in your power to fix the problem. You have to cope with it, for example by not crashing, and not hanging, when it happens. It's also not in the user's power to fix the problem.

The older app worked fine because you used it at a different time when the network connection wasn't lost. And it seems that instead of crying, you should have thought about what is happening. If your network connection is lost, there's nothing you can do except waiting.

And all these things you have been trying are completely pointless; nothing will fix a lost network connection. (Well, at my home making sure that nobody kicked the cable connecting the router to the phone plug would help).

Comment: I tried it over 100 times, it was not chance it had something todo with temporary files I guess.